# How to prove correctness of following algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

i need to prove that following algorithm  works correctly,i know induction,but don't know how to use it here?also  i will be happy  if would know complexity of algorithm,how optimal it is?
what is it's run time?please help me

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#define c 2
//we should take c   more ot equal  then 2
using namespace std;
int multiply(int y,int z){
      // product yz
    if(z==0) return 0;
    return (multiply(c*y,int(z/c))+y*(z %c));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int y=5;
    int z=7;
    cout<<multiply(y,z)<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

thanks

Comment: So, what's the algorithm supposed to do?

Comment: multiply of two integers

Comment: Is it homework? Is the algorithm given in the homework? Or is it designed by you?

Comment: Just compare the result of multiply(y,z) with y*z. If the result is equal for a set of tests, the algorithm is working fine.

Comment: it is self-study,from algorithm design manual

Comment: @JosepRodríguezLópez: Are you suggesting he should look for all possible y,z values? To prove the algorithm works fine he needs a formal proof or to check the results of all possible values, which is practically impossible.

Comment: @amit I assumed he just wanted to check that the algorithm worked fine, not that he wanted to prove that it did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) for `z=0` your function is obviously correct

2) suppose `multiply(x, y)` returns `x*y` for `0 <= y < y0`. Then

```
  x*y
= x*((y/c)*c + y%c)    # by the definition of %
= x*c*(y/c) + x*(y%c)  # distributive, commutative laws
= multiply(x*c, y/c) + x*(y%c) # 0 <= y/c < y, induction hypothesis
```

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a homework, I'm only going to give hints.

First, there's an `if` in the function.
In the case of z=0, proving correctness is trivial.

Next, if z>0, then there are two things to check:

First, the invariant: You have to check that, assuming multiply works correctly with the recursive call, the value returned is indeed the product of the two numbers.

Second: You have to prove that this function eventually returns, i.e. that no matter which numbers you give, eventually you'll get to the point where the function doesn't recursively call itself any more. A hint for this: Look at the binary representation of the arguments, and what multiplication by two and division by two do to it.

At that point, it should also be easy to determine the complexity of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Extract a formula for an iteration. Then prove it for n=1, n=2, .. After that prove the step n => n+1.. if you don't know how to do that ask at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is more a comment then an answer.

Comment: `i know induction,but don't know how to use it here` suggests @dato knows how induction works and what he should be looking for, he is looking for the claim that will lead him to the correctness of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

1. i would not use '*' operator

   multiply(c*y,int(z/c))+y*(z %c)

should be

```
multiply(multiply(c,y),int(z/c))+multiply(y,(z %c))
```

1. as Josep has mentioned do calculation using '*' operator and do the same using ur multiply(). compare results to a level of precision.
2. for getting time run. before executing the time method in main method. call [time library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/)

   time_t startTime= time (NULL);
   cout<<multiply(y,z)<<endl;
   time_t endTime= time (NULL);
   cout<<(endTime-startTime)<<" sec";